# jquery disable submit button based on status array

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

I'm trying to make my own custom form validation.  I want to maintain a status array with each field having it's own key : value (value is either "good" or "bad").  When the array contains a "bad", I want to disable the submit button.

Error/Success messages work next to each field (my ajax works fine), but I can't get the submit button to disable.

```
$(function() {
    // Custom Validation
    var statusArray = {
        'email' : 'good',
        'passC' : 'good',
        'pass1' : 'good',
        'pass2' : 'good'
    }
    $("#email").blur(function() {
        var form_data = {email: $("#email").val()}
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url('lounge/validation/email'); ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                if (msg['status'] == false){
                    $('#email_status').html('<span class="lounge_error">'+msg['message']+'</span>');
                    statusArray['email'] = 'bad';
                }
                else {
                    $('#email_status').html('<span class="lounge_okay">'+msg['message']+'</span>');
                    statusArray['email'] = 'good';
                }
            }
        });
        statusCheck();
        return false;
    })
    // Password fields validation
    $('#change_password').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $('#current_password_status').html('').css({"display": "inline-block"});
            $('#new_password1_status').html('').css({"display": "inline-block"});
            $('#new_password2_status').html('').css({"display": "inline-block"});
            $("#current_password").blur(function() {
                var form_data = {password: $("#current_password").val()}
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= base_url('lounge/validation/password'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result['status'] == false){
                            $('#current_password_status').html('<span class="lounge_error">'+result['message']+'</span>');
                            statusArray['passC'] = 'bad';
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#current_password_status').html('<span class="lounge_okay">'+result['message']+'</span>');
                            statusArray['passC'] = 'good';
                        }
                    }
                });
                statusCheck();
                return false;
            });
            $("#new_password1").blur(function() {
                var form_data = {pass1: $("#new_password1").val()}
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= base_url('lounge/validation/newpass1'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result['status'] == false){
                            $('#new_password1_status').html('<span class="lounge_error">'+result['message']+'</span>');
                            statusArray['pass1'] = 'bad';
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#new_password1_status').html('<span class="lounge_okay">'+result['message']+'</span>');
                            statusArray['pass1'] = 'good';
                        }
                    }
                });
                statusCheck();
                return false;
            });
            $("#new_password2").blur(function() {
                var form_data = {pass2: $("#new_password2").val()}
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?= base_url('lounge/validation/newpass2'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: form_data,
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result['status'] == false){
                            $('#new_password2_status').html('<span class="lounge_error">'+result['message']+'</span>');
                            statusArray['pass2'] = 'bad';
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#new_password2_status').html('<span class="lounge_okay">'+result['message']+'</span>');
                            statusArray['pass2'] = 'good';
                        }
                    }
                });
                statusCheck();
                return false;
            });
        } else {
            $('#current_password_status').html('').css({"display": "none"});
            $('#new_password1_status').html('').css({"display": "none"});
            $('#new_password2_status').html('').css({"display": "none"});

        }
    });

});

function statusCheck() {
    var status = [];
    $.each(statusArray, function(key, value) {
        status.unshift(value);
    });
    if ($.inArray('bad', status) == '-1') {
        $("button[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your status check as follows:

```
function statusCheck() {
    var isValid = true;
    $.each(statusArray, function(key, value) {
        if(value == 'bad')
            isValid = false;
    });
    if (isValid) {
        $("button[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){statusCheck();});
```

Maybe you just missed the calling it on jquery ready part. But this code is better than using an array to check status.

Comment: nune,  I think your answer is closer to the solution than revisions of the $("button[type=submit]") call... I've had  `$("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true)` working with past experiments.  This code still doesn't work, and when I include `statusCheck()` in the ready function, it breaks everything.

Comment: I don't see how it could break everything. Can you provide a jsfiddle? Yes, you can set the attribute value to anything. Most browsers will ignore that part.

Comment: I tried to do a jsfiddle, but the script relies on ajax success messages which pull pages/scripts from my server.  For some reason, it seems not to work on jsfiddle.  To answer your question, when I try `$(function() {statusCheck();}`, nothing works... including my ajax calls to the server to check each field.  Not sure why... haven't quite figured that out yet.

Comment: I'll try to modify this page to fit jsfiddle without any server-side requests.  Coming soon.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a jsfiddle... too many modifications to the code are needed and it would be hard to determine where the exact error is with so many inconsistencies.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pSx4u/ . Change the values in statusArray and test. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the code!  You're right, it works in jsfiddle.  For some reason, when applied to my application, it's not working.  I've abandoned the feature and will rely on the server to perform validation.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true);
```

To this (Jquery 1.6+):

```
$("button[type=submit]").prop('disabled', true);
```

Or this:

```
$("button[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks @fbfcn I tried both suggestions but no success.  I suspect the problem may lie somewhere else... as I've had `$("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true)` working before in other applications.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
  $("button[type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: Thanks @thecodeparadox I tried this but no success. I suspect the problem may lie somewhere else... as I've had `$("button[type=submit]").attr("disabled", true)` working before in other applications.